# Using Docker via Windows console: includes invalid characters $PWD for a local volume name

Tags: python, windows, docker

I try to run a Python program with Docker via the Windows console (Windows 10).

I had made the Windows console be capable of  Docker *Hello, World!*.

But when I run:

```
 docker run -it --rm --name my-running-script -v "$PWD":/usr/src/myapp -w /usr/src/myapp python:2 python test.py
```

I get the error:

> docker: Error response from daemon: create $PWD: volume name invalid: 
>   "$PWD" includes invalid characters for a local volume name, only
>   "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_.-]" are allowed.
>
> See 'docker run --help'.

While running the same code via Docker Quickstart Terminal, it runs well.

I tried to, but I can't solve it. How can I do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mount current directory as a volume in Docker on Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41485217/mount-current-directory-as-a-volume-in-docker-on-windows-10)

Answer (score 111):

I think, the substitution of Linux command `$(pwd)` in Windows is `"%cd%"`.

So, try out following command which might help you.

```
docker run -it --rm --name my-running-script -v "%cd%":/usr/src/myapp -w /usr/src/myapp python:2 python test.py
```

Comment: Presuming a CMD window instead of a PowerShell window?

Comment: Yes. I did not test on powershell though.

Comment: It worked for me. It seems the guide, http://localhost/tutorial/using-bind-mounts/, is written for Linux.

Comment: "%cd%" saved my life. LOL.

Answer (score 15):

Read the documentation: *[Manage data in containers](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/containers/dockervolumes/)*

If you are using Docker Machine on Mac or Windows, your Docker daemon has only limited access to your OS X or Windows filesystem. Docker Machine tries to auto-share your /Users (OS X) or C:\Users (Windows) directory.

So, you can mount files or directories on OS X using:

```
docker run -v /Users/<path>:/<container path> ...
```

On Windows, mount directories using:

```
docker run -v /c/Users/<path>:/<container path> ...`
```

My Docker Machine is on Windows, so instead of  ' "$PWD" ' like:

```
docker run -it --rm --name my-running-script -v "$PWD":/usr/src/myapp -w /usr/src/myapp python:2 python test.py
```

Use  ' /c/Users/your_name ' like:

```
docker run -it --rm --name my-running-script -v /c/Users/cn_pa:/usr/src/myapp -w /usr/src/myapp python:2 python test.py
```

Comment: The documentation link is broken, *"Sorry, we can't find that page"*.

Comment: The fact that you should reference absolute directory paths as `/drive_letter/first_directory/etc` is what I was looking for to allow me to push my volumes to another partition. Thank you.

Answer (score 12):

if you use a bash command line on windows, you will works just placing a / before $ PWD. Something like:

```
docker run -v /$PWD:/src
```

Answer (score 10):

This did work for me in **Powershell**.

```
docker run -p 8080:3000 -v ${pwd}:/var/www -w "/var/www" node npm start
```

Answer (score 2):

On Windows 10, using Cmder (cmd.exe) I came upon this error while in the getting started tutorial on this step: [Part 6: Use binds mounts](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/06_bind_mounts/)

#### Start a dev-mode container

If you are using PowerShell then use this command:

```
 PS> docker run -dp 3000:3000 `
     -w /app -v "$(pwd):/app" `
     node:12-alpine `
     sh -c "yarn install && yarn run dev"
```

But if you are using Command Prompt then use this command:

```
docker run -dp 3000:3000 ^
-w /app -v "%cd%":/app ^
node:12-alpine ^
sh -c "yarn install && yarn run dev"
```

Answer (score 0):

I just replaced $PWD with dir and it worked for me

```
docker run -it --rm -v dir:/src trailofbits/eth-security-toolbox
```

instead of

```
docker run -it --rm -v $PWD:/src trailofbits/eth-security-toolbox
```

I don't much knowledge on these things. So correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

Don't know if you already got it fixed with the solutions provided already but my workaround is that windows don't read bracelets `$(pwd)`.  `${pwd}` did the trick for me.