# docker: Error response from daemon: create ${PWD}: "${PWD}" includes invalid characters for a local volume name,

Tags: python, windows, docker, cmd

I am getting the full error

`docker: Error response from daemon: create ${PWD}: "${PWD}" includes invalid characters for a local volume name, only "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_.-]" are allowed. If you intended to pass a host directory, use absolute path.`

When I try running the command

```
docker run --gpus all --rm -it -v ${PWD}:/home/EEGNet --name EEGNet_inner_speech eegnet_env:latest python experiment.py
```

I am on Windows 10, 21H2, -19044.1706, though it might have to do with the Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-6300U CPU @2.40GHz.
This question [was previously asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35767929/using-docker-via-windows-console-includes-invalid-characters-pwd-for-a-local-v) however if I switch my file path for the ${PWD} such as

```
docker run --gpus all --rm -it -v C:\Users\wesie\EEGNet_inner_speech --name EEGNet_inner_speech eegnet_env:latest python experiment.py

docker run --gpus all --rm -it -v C:\Users\wesie\EEGNet_inner_speech eegnet_env:latest python experiment.py
```

or switch ${PWD} to %cd% as the previous question suggested I get the error

`docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create shim: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: process_linux.go:545: container init caused: Running hook #0:: error running hook: signal: segmentation fault, stdout: , stderr:: unknown.`

Second error asked [here previously in stack overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72158555/docker-error-response-from-daemon-failed-to-create-shim-oci-runtime-create-fa) and [here in Docker's Community](https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-error-response-from-daemon-failed-to-create-shim-oci-runtime-create-failed-container-linux-go-starting-container-process-caused-process-linux-go-container-init-caused-running-hook-0-error-running-hook-signal-segmentation-fault/124306)

Any idea on how to fix these? Full directions:

1. Run `git clone https://github.com/naomike/EEGNet_inner_speech.git`
2. Place dataset under `dataset` directory Build a docker container by
   running docker `image build -t eegnet_env:latest .`
3. Run `docker run --gpus all --rm -it -v ${PWD}:/home/EEGNet --name EEGNet_inner_speech eegnet_env:latest python experiment.py`, and you
   see resulting files created in the directory.